# How to present some text containing stars (*) in bold by RestructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

I need to present in bold the text

xyz:abc:01******-*.***

by **RestructuredText** syntax. Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: \*\*text\*\* with text = \\*\\*\\* (three stars) = \*\*\\*\\*\\*\*\*

Comment: Thank you. It works. You may create an answer and I will mark it as a solution.

**xyz:abc:01\*\*\*\*\*\*-\*.\*\*\***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you could use a backslash character ("\"r) in front of characters which have a particular meaning in reStructuredText different from beeing "just a character". If you want to display asterisks in you text just user "\*".

The text from your example above should be then

```
xyz:abc:01\*\*\*\*\*\*-\*.\*\*\*
```

Comment: To be more correct: `**xyz:abc:01\*\*\*\*\*\*-\*.\*\*\***`

Comment: Yes, this was more correct. Thank you for accepting my answer anyhow.